# Find min and max of cumulative sum in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, tuples, morelinq

I have the following function which I am using to find the terminal accumulative positive and negative value, which is working:

```
public class CumulativeTotal
{
    [Test]
    public void CalculatesTerminalValue()
    {
        IEnumerable<decimal> sequence = new decimal[] { 10, 20, 20, -20, -50, 10 };

        var values = FindTerminalValues(sequence);
        Assert.That(values.Item1, Is.EqualTo(-20));
        Assert.That(values.Item2, Is.EqualTo(50));

        Assert.Pass();
    }

    public static Tuple<decimal,decimal> FindTerminalValues(IEnumerable<decimal> values)
    {
        decimal largest = 0;
        decimal smallest = 0;
        decimal current = 0;

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            current += value;
            if (current > largest)
                largest = current;
            else if (current < smallest)
                smallest = current;
        }

        return new Tuple<decimal, decimal>(smallest,largest);
    }
}
```

However, in the interests of learning, how could i implement with Linq?

I can see a package [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ), but not sure where to start!

Comment: I may have terminologies mixed up, this is a essentially a ledger and the values in the sequence deltas to add. It is -20 as a minimum as 10 + 20 + 20 - 20 - 50 = -20 (and then doesn't go lower than that)

Comment: `values.Aggregate((min: 0, max: 0), (ac, current) => (current < ac.min ? current : ac.min, current > ac.max : current : ac.max))`

Comment: You should initialize `smallest` to `decimal.MaxValue` and `largest` to `decimal.MinValue` that way it will still work if the max sum is negative or the min sum is positive.

Comment: @AluanHaddad That's not keeping track of the running sum.

Comment: @juharr I noticed he wasn't using the running sum so I didn't bother with it.

Comment: This is one of the use cases where i prefer a simple loop. Best what you can get with LINQ is either not as efficient or not as readable, worst case both.

Comment: @AluanHaddad He is `current += value;` it's just a poorly named variable.

Comment: This does fail on `IEnumerable<decimal> sequence = new decimal[] { 10, 20, 20, -20, 50, 10 };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major flaw in the code you've presented is that if the running sum of the the sequence stays below zero or above zero the whole time then the algorithm incorrectly returns zero as one of the terminals.

Take this:

```
IEnumerable<decimal> sequence = new decimal[] { 10, 20, };
```

Your current algorithm returns `(0, 30)` when it should be `(10, 30)`.

To correct that you must start with the first value of the sequence as the default minimum and maximum.

Here's an implementation that does that:

```
public static (decimal min, decimal max) FindTerminalValues(IEnumerable<decimal> values)
{
    if (!values.Any())
        throw new System.ArgumentException("no values");
        
    decimal first = values.First();
    
    IEnumerable<decimal> scan = values.Scan((x, y) => x + y);

    return scan.Aggregate(
        (min: first, max: first),
        (a, x) =>
        (
            min: x < a.min ? x : a.min, 
            max: x > a.max ? x : a.max)
        );
}
```

It uses `System.Interactive` to get the `Scan` operator (but you could use `MoreLinq`.

However, the one downside to this approach is that `IEnumerable<decimal>` is not guaranteed to return the same values every time. You either need to (1) pass in a `decimal[]`, `List<decimal>`, or other structure that will always return the same sequence, or (2) ensure you only iterate the `IEnumerable<decimal>` once.

Here's how to do (2):

```
public static (decimal min, decimal max) FindTerminalValues(IEnumerable<decimal> values)
{
    var e = values.GetEnumerator();
    if (!e.MoveNext())
        throw new System.ArgumentException("no values");

    var terminal = (min: e.Current, max: e.Current);
    decimal value = e.Current;

    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        value += e.Current;
        terminal = (Math.Min(value, terminal.min), Math.Max(value, terminal.max));
    }

    return terminal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try standard Linq `Aggregate` method:

```
// Let's return named tuple: unlike min, max 
// current .Item1 and .Item2 are not readable
public static (decimal min, decimal max) FindTerminalValues(IEnumerable<decimal> values) {
  //public method arguments validation
  if (values is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));

  (var min, var max, _) = values
    .Aggregate((min: decimal.MaxValue, max: decimal.MinValue, curr: 0m), 
               (s, a) => (Math.Min(s.min, s.curr + a), 
                          Math.Max(s.max, s.curr + a),
                          s.curr + a));

  return (min, max);
}
```

Comment: you can do it directly like : `return values.Aggregate((min: 0m, max: 0m, curr: 0m), (s, a) => (Math.Min(s.min, s.curr + a), Math.Max(s.max, s.curr + a), s.curr + a), r => (r.min, r.max));`

Comment: This does fail on `IEnumerable<decimal> sequence = new decimal[] { 10, 20, 20, -20, 50, 10 };`.

Comment: @Enigmativity: my bad, good catch! it should have been `(min: decimal.MaxValue, max: decimal.MinValue, curr: 0m)` initialization; I've edited the answer.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - Nice use of `decimal.MaxValue` & `decimal.MinValue`.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can use [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq) like this, it has the [Scan](https://morelinq.github.io/2.9/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Scan__1.htm) method.

```
public static Tuple<decimal, decimal> FindTerminalValues(IEnumerable<decimal> values)
{
    var cumulativeSum = values.Scan((acc, x) => acc + x).ToList();

    decimal min = cumulativeSum.Min();
    decimal max = cumulativeSum.Max();

    return new Tuple<decimal, decimal>(min, max);
}
```

The Scan extension method generates a new sequence by applying a function to each element in the input sequence, using the previous element as an accumulator. In this case, the function is simply the addition operator, so the Scan method generates a sequence of the cumulative sum of the input sequence.

Comment: If `values` is long `.ToList()` brings *unwanted overhead* (current OP solution doesn't want extra memory)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko OP has not mentioned about extra memory anywhere in question. and  asked for a solution using MoreLinq

Comment: This does ***succeed*** on `IEnumerable<decimal> sequence = new decimal[] { 10, 20, 20, -20, 50, 10 };`.

Comment: @viveknuna - It's interesting that the `System.Interactive` version of `Scan` behaves differently from the `MoreLinq` version. `Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Scan((acc, x) => acc + x)` returns `{3}` for the former, and `{1, 3}` for the latter.

Comment: What I don't like is the `.Scan(acc, (acc, x) => ...)` overload. `MoreLinq` outputs the accumulator as the first value. I feel that's wrong.

Comment: @Enigmativity I didn't get your last comment

Comment: Take a look at `Enumerable.Range(1, 9).Scan(1000, (acc, x) => acc + x)`. It produces 10 values, not 9 and it starts with 1000 with `MoreLinq`. With `System.Reactive` it starts with `1001` and produces `9` values - the same as the source. I think that's expected output.

Comment: @Enigmativity got it now. Thank you for clarification and spending time :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Aggregate method in LINQ to achieve this.
The Aggregate method applies a function to each element in a sequence and returns the accumulated result. It takes as parameter an initial accumulator object to keep track of the smallest and largest function.

```
public static Tuple<decimal,decimal> FindTerminalValues(IEnumerable<decimal> values)
{
    return values.Aggregate(
        // Initial accumulator value:
        new Tuple<decimal, decimal>(0, 0),
        // Accumulation function:
        (acc, value) =>
        {
            // Add the current value to the accumulator:
            var current = acc.Item1 + value;
            // Update the smallest and largest accumulated values:
            var smallest = Math.Min(current, acc.Item1);
            var largest = Math.Max(current, acc.Item2);
            // Return the updated accumulator value:
            return new Tuple<decimal, decimal>(smallest, largest);
        });
}
```

Comment: If you run your code on `new decimal[] { 10, 20, 20, -20, -50, 10 }` (example from the question), you'll get `(-70, 20)` instead of `(-20, 50)`. Move `current` out of Linq query.

Comment: This does fail on `IEnumerable<decimal> sequence = new decimal[] { 10, 20, 20, -20, 50, 10 };`.